# Old robot movie with robots in cages being hurt at a carnival show

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

This was definitely not a movie I was supposed to be watching for my age. That's the reason this movie is very faint in my memory. I have spent well over 4 hours, on and off, looking for this movie with no avail. This is all I remember (not sure if it's all accurate):

- Movie had robots that some ended up hurt/dying
- Think I remember cages being involved
- I want to say the robots where part of a carnival show or something

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is [A.I. Artificial Intelligence.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence)

The scene with the robots in cages is below.

Comment: Valorum is really the [DeepQA](https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_group.php?id=2099) system of SciFi StackExchange. I wonder whether [Yukito Kishiro's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_Alita) was used as inspiration here?

Comment: This is old? What comes to mind when I hear "old" is 80s movies, like "Flight of the Navigator". Now I feel old.

Comment: This is old? What comes to mind when I hear "old" is 50s movies, like "Conquest of Space". Now I feel old.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks so much @valorum . Crazy how I only remembered the scary scene, but I'm not surprised, considering I was probably 8 or 9 at the time. This movie really stuck in my brain and I'm glad I can watch it again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: See also the older question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/197101/28516 (answer not accepted except in a deleted answer post).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: old to me is Metropolis or Wolfman from 1940.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I've duped them off. Their answer should have been converted to a comment