# Movie about robotic child seeking to wake his mother

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

This was a movie about a couple that cannot have kids, so they create a robotic child. But there were some kind of natural disaster and the human race is extinct, and when other people came they found the robotic child, and he was looking for his mother.

The responsible person told him that he can bring his mother back for one day only if he could bring him her DNA, so the boy remembers that one day he grabbed her hair and start looking for it and his mother came back to life.

Comment: Related:https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/197102/28516

Comment: It's amazing to me that you've remembered the one part of this movie that most viewers would rather forget.  I actually really loved this movie up until that last bit.  Basically everything after the screen went black at the Blue Fairy statue - they should've ended it there and it would've been a near-perfect (if tragic) ending, but then "Two thousand years passed..." I spent the last 20 minutes of the film just silently screaming "WHY?!"

Comment: @DarrelHoffman fun fact: there's still a debate on whether the film's ending is entirely on Spielberg to blame, or the ending is actually the original Kubrick's vision. Spielberg claims the ending was 100% Kubrick's idea and that he just wanted to respect that despite producers not liking it, while other sources claim that, while the ending was indeed written by Kubrick, he was never very convinced it would work.

Comment: @JoshPart - The general consensus seems to be that the ending didn't work, regardless of who Spielberg tries to pin it on.

Comment: @Valorum I know (and agree with) that; I just find curious how a lot of people still believe it was Spielberg's idea to not let the movie end in such a dark, depressing tone

Answer (score 29):

This the 2001 Spielberg film [*A.I. Artificial Intelligence*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/), the story of the life of David, an artificial boy created to be a companion to childless couples.

Quoting from the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence#Plot):

> Two thousand years later, **humanity has become extinct** and Manhattan is now buried under glacial ice. The Mecha have evolved into an advanced form, and a group of them called the Specialists have become interested in learning about humanity. They find and revive David and Teddy. David walks to the frozen Blue Fairy statue, which collapses when he touches it. **The Specialists reconstruct the Swinton family home from David's memories** and explain to him, via an interactive image of the Blue Fairy, that it is impossible to make David a real boy. However, **at David's insistence, they use their scientific knowledge to recreate Monica through genetic material from the strand of hair that Teddy kept**. This Monica can live for only one day, and the process cannot be repeated. David spends his happiest day with Monica, and as she falls asleep in the evening, she tells David that she has always loved him: "the everlasting moment he had been waiting for", the narrator says; "David falls asleep as well and goes to that place 'where dreams are born.'"

Comment: Wasn't the film by produced by Stanley Kubrick, but Spielberg after he died. I think that might explain the abrupt change of tone 20 minutes before the end

Answer (score 19):

This is almost certainly *[AI: Artificial Intelligence](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/)*.

David's parents already have a child, but he's in cryosleep due to an untreatable illness. At the end of the film David is (or rather the super-intelligent evolved robots who find him are) able to resurrect his adoptive mother because he cut off a lock of her hair.

Comment: Factually wrong. That is not David that meets his (btw. not resurrected) parents.

Comment: @TomTom - Who do you think it is then?

Comment: Ah, watch the movie. The "David" in the end is not the real person but the robot child. The parents also are not "real".

Comment: @TomTom - I don't see anyone calling David a real boy, [hence the tagline](https://cdn.traileraddict.com/vidquad/warner-bros-pictures/artificial/1.jpg)

Comment: It is implied by the term "cryoSLEEP" right in the first sentence. If my car runs out of battery, it is not sleeping. A robot that runs out of energy is not sleeping. This implies a boy.

Comment: @TomTom - Yes, it's Monica's real son (Martin) that is in cryosleep.